# イベントブロックが動作しない（英語版、「When aibo is said high five」のブロック）

Tags: aibo-visual-programming

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]aibo本体の認識言語を英語にして使用しています。ビジュアルプログラミングのaiboのイベントにおける「aiboが "はいたっち" といわれたとき」の英語版「when aibo is said "high five"」ブロックを使ったプログラムを作成し、aiboに「High five」と言っても認識しません。認識させるコツはありますでしょうか。

以下は試してみました。

1. 「High five」を私の声ではなく別の音源（コンピュータ音声など）で試しましたが、認識しませんでした。
2. 他のブロックのフレーズ（Sit, Shake, Lay downなど）は私の声でもコンピュータ音声でもスムーズに認識します。
3. ビジュアルプログラミングを解除した通常モードの状態では、私の声による「High five」をスムーズに認識します（実際にハイタッチをします）。
4. aibo本体の認識言語を日本語に切り替え、「aiboが "はいたっち" といわれたとき」を試したところスムーズに認識します。